# Windows Virtual PC: not enough system resources

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I need to create multiple Virtual machines under Win7.
I installed Windows Virtual PC and created a base virtual machine (installed Win XP and other software needed).

I then duplicate that machine but unfortunately, when attempting to launch the 3rd instance, I receive the following error message: "Could not start be cause there are not enough system resources or memory in your computer".

I can't figure out which resource is creating the problem since:

- Memory: I have 6Gb of RAM and each instance is configured to have 512mb of
  memory (I currently have ~3Gb of free memory while running 2
  instances)
- Hard drive: more than 50Gb free
- CPU: the 2 instances are consuming ~30% of CPU (quad-core)
- Video memory: each instance is configured in 1024x768 resolution. My current windows session is 1920x1200 resolution. My video card is a GeForce GT525M: could it be that there is insufficient video RAM?

Any idea/hint on what the issue could be is more than welcome.

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: How many cores does each instance configured to detect?

Comment: An old version of google Chrome used to cause a problem like this (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115546) Look for and turn off similar or other background tasks and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: When opening VM's task manager, it shows only 1 CPU core: could this be an issue? Re Google Chrome: I have the latest version installed. Thx